# jsoncpp empty root node with comment

Tags: jsoncpp, root-node

Using jsoncpp, if I use the following code, I get a root node with a comment and a Json::ValueType of nullValue:

```
std::string somejson("// Configuration options\
{\
// Default encoding for text\
\"encoding\" : \"UTF-8\",\
\
// Plug-ins loaded at start-up\
\"plug-ins\" : [\
    \"python\",\
    \"c++\",\
    \"ruby\"\
    ],\
    \
// Tab indent size\
\"indent\" : { \"length\" : 3, \"use_space\": true }\
}");
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(somejson, root);
```

However, if I create an empty root node myself and add a comment, it bombs out:

```
Json::Value rootNode = Json::Value(Json::nullValue);
rootNode.setComment("My wonderful comment", Json::commentBefore);
```

Am I doing something really stupid? Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious. A simple trace through reveals that Value::CommentInfo::setComment asserts that the comment must begin with a /

My comment didn't. More coffee needed.